# Java Swing - paintComponent() not drawing my Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I want to add to an `ArrayList` of `Thread`'s which represent a ball with (x,y) coordinated and a `move()` method a new ball `Thread` every 5 seconds.
So my `JPanel` implements `Runnable` and in there i add to the `ArrayList` a new ball `Thread`.
In the `paintComponent()` method i use `foreach` loop to iterate the `ArrayList` of ball `Thread`'s and start their `Thread` which moves them and call for `repaint()`. Problem is i i don't see any drawing at all(Only the player drawing).

**MyPanel.java**:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener,Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE; 
    private static final Color NPC_BALLS_COLOR = Color.RED;

    // The player is an oval
    private int playerRadius = 20;
    private int playerX;
    private int playerY;

    // True - first player position, false - otherwise
    private boolean playerPosition = true;

    // Array of all the balls threads
    private ArrayList<BallThread> balls = new ArrayList<BallThread>();

    private Thread generateBallsThread;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.setBackground(MyPanel.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);

        this.generateBallsThread = new Thread();
        generateBallsThread.start();
    }


    // Drawing

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        final double PANEL_WIDTH = this.getWidth();
        final double PANEL_HEIGHT = this.getHeight();

        if (this.playerPosition)
        {
            this.playerX = (int)(PANEL_WIDTH / 2 - this.playerRadius);
            this.playerY = (int)(PANEL_HEIGHT / 2 - this.playerRadius);
            this.playerPosition = false;
        }

        // Drawing the player
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(playerX,playerY, this.playerRadius * 2, this.playerRadius * 2);

        // Drawing npc's balls
        g.setColor(MyPanel.NPC_BALLS_COLOR);
        for (BallThread ball: this.balls)
        {
            ball.start();
            g.fillOval(ball.getBall().getX(), ball.getBall().getY(), 
                    ball.getBall().radius, ball.getBall().radius);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    // Keyboard listeners

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        switch (e.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_W: // Up
            {
                this.playerY -= 5;
                repaint();
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_S: // Down
            {
                this.playerY += 5;
                repaint();
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_D: // Right
            {
                this.playerX += 5;
                repaint();
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.VK_A: // Left
            {
                this.playerX -= 5;
                repaint();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public int getBallXStartingPositionFromTop()
    {
        return (int) Math.random() * 101; // 0 - 100
    }

    //public int getBallYStartingPositionFromLeft()
    //{
    //  return (int) Math.random() * 101; // 0 - 100
    //}

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * Class for the balls threads.
     *
     */
    public class BallThread extends Thread
    {
        private Ball ball;

        public BallThread(Ball ball)
        {
            this.ball.setX(ball.getX());
            this.ball.setY(ball.getY());
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                this.ball.move();
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                repaint(); // Execute paintComponent() method
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public Ball getBall()
        {
            return this.ball;
        }

        public void setBall(Ball ball) 
        {
            this.ball = ball;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // 5 seconds
            this.balls.add(new BallThread(new Ball(20,20)));

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }








} // End of MyPanel class
```

**Ball.java**:

```
public class Ball 
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int velocity = 1;
    public int radius = 10;
    public boolean directionX = true; // True - right, false - left
    public boolean directionY = false; // True - up, false - down

    public static final int Y_STARTING_POSITION_FROM_TOP = 0;

    public Ball(int x, int y) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Ball()
    {

    }

    public int getX() 
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) 
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) 
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void move()
    {
        if (this.directionX) // Right
        {
            this.x += this.velocity;
        }
        else // Left
        {
            this.x -= this.velocity;
        }
        if (this.directionY) // Up
        {
            this.y -= this.velocity;
        }
        else
        {
            this.y += this.velocity;
        }
    }


}
```

And i omitted a simple `JFrame` class and a `main()` who generates the `JFrame` with the `JPanel` added to it.

Any ideas why i don't get to see the drawing of the ball `Thread`'s?

Comment: Try not calling `repaint();`. Don't know anything about this.. just a suggestion.

Comment: @3kings That's not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    this.generateBallsThread = new Thread();
    generateBallsThread.start();
```

That does nothing. It is an empty Thread with no logic.

I think you want

```
    this.generateBallsThread = new BallsThread();
    generateBallThread.start();
```

Also, you should not be using a Thread for animation. You should be using a `Swing Timer`. Any logic that updates the state of a Swing component should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Swing Timers`.

Comment: But `generateBallsThread ` is a `Thread` object not `BallsThread` object.

Comment: I will check the Swing Timer but i want to succeed this with `Thread`'s first.

Comment: BallThread extends Thread and contains your execution logic. The same way MyPanel extend JPanel. This is what "inheritance" is all about. I suggest you read your text book or search the web for more information if you don't understand the concept.

Comment: Oh you are right. But I dont have an empty constructor for `BallsThread`. I will have right now and see if it's working.

Comment: It giving me a `NullPointerException` `MyPanel$BallThread.<init>` `MyPanel.<init>` and `MyFrame.<init>`

Comment: So the problem asked by this question has been solved. That is you know the answer why the Thread was not being invoked, so the answer should be "accepted". Now it is time for you to debug the NullPointerException. That is what programming is about. You write code and test it. When it doesn't work you debug it. You can't ask a question on the forum every time you get a NPE. You need to learn to problem solve yourself. The error message will tell you the statement causing the problem. So figure out which variable is null and fix it.

Comment: Ok man thanks. I will accept the answer no doubt. But tell me , Is my implementation of this is correct? Put aside the Swing Timer.

Comment: @God, I didn't look at it in detail but it looks reasonable except for the constructor. There is no need to set the x/y of the Ball. However you do need to actually save the Ball parameter. That is you need `this.ball = ball;`, Since you want to reference the "ball" variable in the run() method.